# Mathematica 8 won't start - Error Code 499

Tags: warning-messages, system, installation

I am pretty dumbfolded on this one and there seem to be virtually no clues around the net. The only thing vaguely related is a fairly similar (unsuccessful) question on reddit:

https://m.reddit.com/r/Mathematica/comments/1dpcev/help_me_mathematica_wont_start_anymore_and_i_need/

I am running Mathematica 8 using a school licence server - it crashed the other day because my VPN session ran out. After that I have no longer been able to launch successfully.

Multiple uninstall / registry clean attempts have remained unsuccessful - any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: Have you contacted Wolfram Support? This seems like a question that they would be better equipped to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - I was successful on my own. Since the Wolfram Support does not mention Error 499 I will put the answer link here.

http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

Deleting C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica did the trick for me.

Comment: Errors of this kind during startup are usually due to the corruption of one of the files in `$UserBaseDirectory`. Deleting that directory (except, perhaps, the `Licensing` subfolder) usually does the trick.

Comment: Yes that did the trick - I was mostly surprised not to find any mention of the prominently reported error code anywhere.